# Flutter performace issue with google_mobile_ads and youtube_player_flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying show youtube video and google ads on screen, but unfortunately app slows down the performance, when video starts the banner ad get overlap and device start to hang also it cause app to force close, and sometime it makes device to force restart.

What I have tried

- Removing unnecessary code
- tried using diffrence ad packages firebase_admob, admob_flutter, etc.
- tried creating new app, but as result still the same.
- tried using flutter_player_iframe

can someone suggest what i am doing wrong ? I want to play youtube video as well as show ad.

here is the details.

> flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

> pubspecs.yaml

```
name: Awesome App
description: Awesome app with flutter

version: 2.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2

  flutter_html: ^0.11.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  provider: ^4.0.5
  share: 0.6.5+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  localstorage: ^3.0.6+9
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1
  toast: ^0.1.5
  url_launcher: ^5.4.5
  
  #notification
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.3
  notification_permissions: 0.4.8
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.2

  #youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+7
  youtube_player_iframe: ^1.2.0+2
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0+2
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/awesome-app-icon.jpg"

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
 
  assets:
    - assets/
```

> GoogleAds.dart

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class GoogleAds extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GoogleAdsState createState() => _GoogleAdsState();
}

class _GoogleAdsState extends State<GoogleAds> {
  bool isAdLoaded = false;
  BannerAd myBanner1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    super.initState();

    if(!isAdLoaded){
      showAd();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {

    super.dispose();
    myBanner1?.dispose();
  }

  void showAd() {
    myBanner1 = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-1126299876360597/4931129379',
      size: AdSize.banner,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (_) {
          setState(() {
            isAdLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('$BannerAd failedToLoad: $error');
        },
      ),
    );
    myBanner1.load();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return isAdLoaded ? Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner1),
      width: myBanner1.size.width.toDouble(),
      height: 72.0,
    ) : Container(
      height: 72.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Google Ad"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> YoutubeDemo.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

class YoutubeAppDemo extends StatefulWidget {

  String video_id = '';

  YoutubeAppDemo({this.video_id = ''});


  @override
  _YoutubeAppDemoState createState() => _YoutubeAppDemoState();
}

class _YoutubeAppDemoState extends State<YoutubeAppDemo> {
  YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: widget.video_id,
      params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
        //startAt: const Duration(minutes: 1, seconds: 36),
        showControls: true,
        showFullscreenButton: true,
        desktopMode: true,
        autoPlay: false,
        enableJavaScript: true,
        privacyEnhanced: true,
      ),
    );
    _controller.onEnterFullscreen = () {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      ]);
    };
    _controller.onExitFullscreen = () {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        _controller.play();
      });
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(DeviceOrientation.values);
      });
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const player = YoutubePlayerIFrame();
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child : LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (kIsWeb && constraints.maxWidth > 800) {
            return Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Expanded(child: player),
              ],
            );
          }
          return ListView(
            children: [
              YoutubePlayerControllerProvider(
                child: player,
                controller: _controller,
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

> home_screen.dart

```
class PostDetails extends StatefulWidget {

  final RecentPosts post;
  PostDetails(this.post);

  @override
  _PostDetailsState createState() => _PostDetailsState();
}

class _PostDetailsState extends State<PostDetails> {

  String id = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    var get_id = widget.post.videoID.split("/");
    id = get_id.last;
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          leading: BackButton(
              color: Colors.white
          ),
          title : Text("Awesome App ")
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                id.isNotEmpty ? YoutubeAppDemo(video_id: id,) : Container(),
                
                Container(
                    child: GoogleAds()
                )
              ],
            )
        ),
    );

  }
}
```